# How to present UIViewController like Gmail or Wunderlist 2

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiviewcontroller, gmail

I want to be able to present my UIViewController like this:

http://upld.im/f/awU+
http://upld.im/f/CO9+

How do I do this?? Please Help

Comment: I would also like to know.

Comment: One way to do this is to learn how to use the `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController` classes, particularly subclassing the view controller's view and overriding its components. By doing this, you can customize its appearance. But there's simply no way to write a self-contained project into a Stack Overflow answer that demonstrates this — you'll need to do some homework, going through tutorials and learning how these components work.

Comment: I second @AlexReynolds answer, but for now you could have a look at this github project: https://github.com/kentnguyen/KNSemiModalViewController.

Comment: The supplement of the answers above, another github project: https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/PushBackAnimation

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the pics do not show up anymore so I am not sure if I answer your question...

If you are looking for sliding views you can check out this one:
https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels

There is also a list with alternatives at the bottom. Personally I use the following:
https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. 
https://github.com/ucu072/HCPushBackAnimation

Detailed animation, there is a need to develop a little more.

Answer (score 0):

I created a UIViewController category to mimic the modal animation shown in the Gmail app when composing a new message. It is called [MFFadeBackModalAnimation](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFFadeBackModalAnimation). It wraps around the native API for presenting and dismissing view controllers so it should integrate well with your existing app.